# difference between React router.push and router.replace?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

What is the difference between **React**  **router.push** and **router.replace**?

Answer (score 39):

The router history works like a `stack` of `routes`. When you use the `router.replace`, you're overwritting the top of the the stack. When using the `router.push`, it adds a new route to the top of the `stack`.

The router history allows you to go back to the last page. For example, when the user navigates to a invalid route, you can use the `router.replace` to prevent the user to navigate back to the invalid route.

Answer (score 23):

The history of pages you visit in your web browser is like a `stack` data structure. You can either `push` a new record onto the top of the history stack or you can `replace` the top record. If you use `push`, and then hit the browser's back button, it will take you back to the page you are currently on, but if you use `replace` it will take you two pages back.