# React Routing : How can I be redirected to matching tab according to url?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs, react-router-dom

I have been stuck for several days for this problem.
My problem is how to jump to purposing tab when I enter url of that tab.

You can find my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-orla-k0bug?file=/src/App.tsx)

In this code I made a tab using material-ui tabs component.
And as you can see from the working example in codesandbox, I attached tab **suburls** after the **page url** with the delimiter `#`.

This is done by `handleChange` method.

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const location = useLocation();

const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
  setValue(newValue);
  history.replace({
    hash: `${tabs[newValue].suburl}`
  });
};
```

And handleChange method is called on Tabs component `onChange` props.
Like this:

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  aria-label="Top Statistic Tabs"
>
  {TabHeaders}
</Tabs>
```

You can see url changes when toggling different tabs in working example.

However, my problem is the reverse is not working.
When you enter a tab url and press enter, it does not jump to matching tab.
I think this is because matching router is not defined to each urls but not be sure and don't know how to do it.

The skeleton code is from https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs and I just added suburl adding part.

Please help me by answering anything you know.

1. React version : 17.0.2
2. React-router-dom version : 4.3.4
3. Material-ui version: 4.12.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codesandbox is [updated](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-matsumoto-uyv6h?file=/src/Tabs.tsx). Please review it.

Active tab is being controlled by the index and it worked fine, when you manually click on the tab and updating the index. The problem on refreshing the page is due to this below code in initialization.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
```

On initialization, you're always setting the first tab as active tab instead of taking the location hash into account. To solve this issue, one of the solution is you can use a ternary check to see if there is some hash in the location object and initialize the value state based on that.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
location?.hash === "#tokentxnsErc20"
  ? 2
  : location?.hash === "#internaltx"
  ? 1
  : 0
);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Junaid. Your answer is awesome. I made a slight change to codesandbox for general usability of this component. It works fine on codesandbox. But on actual browser I always have to refresh twice to be redirected to the matching tab. What is the reason? And where did you get this answer? I wanna know the meaning of `location?.hash`. Thanks.

Comment: @VladislavErmoshin I've updated the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-matsumoto-uyv6h?file=/src/Tabs.tsx). Please take a look.
I've added comments to the code changes to solve the issue. First I've updated the history.replace with history.push. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954837/difference-between-react-router-push-and-router-replace) is some explanation on difference between both methods. Also updated the handleChange method. Lastly, I've added a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to update the index as soon as some change in location.

Comment: hash is a property inside the Location object, which contains the part after #. Using useEffect will update the tab state as soon as the url is updated. Please let me know, if this still not fixed the issue.
I've also added some links to additional reading material, which'll help in better understand some of the topics.

Comment: If you're referring to ?. in the location?.hash, that is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) feature of the JS.